# My Logstash container can't handle the traffic, but the host CPU/MEM is idle

Tags: docker, containers, logstash

I'm using Logstash to parse and aggregate the nginx connection log. (around 3000 events/sec). I believe the aggregating is the bottleneck and what happened is my Logstash has a slower rate to process the log than the written rate of the log. So there is a growing gap between the timestamp each event is written into the file and the @timestamp which Logstash appended to the event. Eventually, Logstash is going to drop some events.

But I checked the usage of the host machine, the average CPU usage is only about 50%, and the memory is not an issue too. Is there any other stuff causing this bottleneck for Logstash?

Also, I didn't see anything wrong in the log of the Logstash. The reason I know it will drop the events is from Kibana.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've never done much logstash optimization, but there's a few insight there: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/tuning-logstash.html. In your case it look like you should at least increase the `pipeline.workers` value.

Comment: For `pipeline.batch.size`, you'd have to make sure that the JVM memory isn't reaching it max size before increasing it. If there are grok filters, try to anchor the regexes with `^$` to speed them up and limit their complexity.

Comment: If the traffic fluctuate during the day, it could be interesting to push the logs in a queue like redis and have logstash consume it: it would spread the load more evenly during the day. Also the rate depends on the elasticsearch speed, you'd have to check if there are slowdown there.

Comment: I've tried to increase the number of works, but it doesn't really help. I think if the number of workers exceeds the number of cores you have, it just won't help that much.

Comment: The doc I've linked seem to disagree: `Good results can even be found increasing this number past the number of available processors `.  Then maybe the issue is on the elasticsearch side, it can't index the logs as quickly as logstash can send them, so it's slowing everything down: you could compare by removing the elasticsearch output.